# Simulate keydown event in JEST

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-jest

I have an event listener in my JS controllerwhich i want to simulate in JEST case.
event listener goes like this

*const element = this.template.querySelector('Something');
element.addEventListener('keyboardEvent', this.handleKeyboardevent);*

Comment: Take a look at [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638385/simulate-keydown-on-document-for-jest-unit-testing). It suggests dispatching a keydown or keypress event of your own. May work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get a handle on the `element` that has the event listener:

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { keyCode: 32 });
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to tweak your event listener to listen for the specific keyboard events rather than `keyboardEvent` like you have in the original code.

```
const element = this.template.querySelector('Something'); 
element.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyboardevent);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, I'll look at it